# jQuery UI: animation won't stop after .progressbar() finishes and both fade away

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, animation, progress-bar

I'm trying to rig a `.progressbar()` and a **flashing** `<span>` element so that, when the `.progressbar()` finishes loading, both disappear. Instead, the `<span>` element doesn't stop flashing, even after it fades away. It just keeps going. I've tried using a boolean variable and some if statements, but that doesn't work.

Here's a link to what I've got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/mnbishop017/XqH6B/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest a few changes as shown in the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ws4Lz/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var begin = $("#begin");
    var intervalHook, timeoutHook, val = 0;

    begin.progressbar({
        value: 0,
        max: 100
    });

    $("#begin,#loading").fadeIn(4000);

    intervalHook = setInterval(function () {
        $("#loading").fadeIn(1000, function () {
            $(this).delay(100).fadeOut(1000);
        });
    }, 2500);

    function progress() {
        val = begin.progressbar("value") || 0;
        begin.progressbar("value", val + 1);
        if (val < 100) {
            timeoutHook = setTimeout(progress, 100);
        }
        if (val == 100) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutHook);
            clearInterval(intervalHook);
            $("#begin,#loading").fadeOut(4000);
        }
    }

    timeoutHook = setTimeout(progress, 3000);
});
```

1. make use of `clearInterval` and `clearTimeout`. You can pass the values returned from `setInterval` and `setTimeout` respectively to stop these from firing once your `.progressbar()` has reached its max value.
2. Separate the `fadeIn`/`fadeOut` functionality from the `progress` function. This way, your `fadeIn`/`fadeOut` logic won't be affected every time `progress()` is called.
3. Make sure that the interval you specify in the `setInterval` call allows for your animations to complete. Initially you have a 1000 ms interval specified for animation operations that will take 4100 ms to complete.

Answer (score 2):

It behaves that way because you are setting an interval, but you don't stop it.

Try the following:

First, place your timer in a variable, e.g.:

```
// (simply put var timer = before your excisting interval)
// key-word "var" is not necessary
var timer = setInterval(function(){ (...)
```

Then, evaluate each interval whether the timer may be deleted. This might be the easiest if you evaluate the value in the interval itself. Pseudo-example:

```
if(foo == 100) {
    clearInterval(timer);
}
```

This should do the trick. :)

Answer (score 1):

- You can also use the option "complete" of the progressbar function.
  It makes your code cleaner since you don't need any counter nor if
  statement to check "if loading == true" or whatever.
- I would also set 2 interval variables since the progress bar and the blicking effect
  ar not synchronized:

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var begin = $("#begin").fadeIn(4000);
      var loading = $("#loading").fadeIn(4000);
      begin.progressbar({
          value: 0,
          max: 100,
          complete: function(event, ui){
              begin.fadeOut(4000);
              loading.fadeOut(4000);
              clearInterval(barinterval);
              clearInterval(blinkinterval);
          }
      });

      var barinterval = setInterval(function(){
              begin.progressbar("value", begin.progressbar("value") + 1);
              },100);

      var blinkinterval = setInterval(function(){
          loading.fadeIn(500, function(){
              $(this).delay(100).fadeOut(500);
              });
          },1500);
  });
  ```

http://jsfiddle.net/XqH6B/20/